# ¿Cómo puedo obtener elementos coincidentes en python?

Tags: python

Llevo unos días buscando y no encuentro la consulta que necesito, estoy tratando de hacer un programa que me compare dos archivos .txt y en uno restante se me guarde los elementos coincidentes. Os muestro un ejemplo de lo que busco:

Archivo 1:

```
Nombre Apellido 1
Nombre Apellido 3
Nombre Apellido 4
```

Archivo 2:

```
Nombre Apellido 1; Correo: Teléfono: Edad: 
Nombre Apellido 2; Correo: Teléfono: Edad: 
Nombre Apellido 3; Correo: Teléfono: Edad: 
Nombre Apellido 4; Correo: Teléfono: Edad: 
Nombre Apellido 5; Correo: Teléfono: Edad:
```

Output:

```
Nombre Apellido 1; Correo: Teléfono: Edad: 
Nombre Apellido 3; Correo: Teléfono: Edad: 
Nombre Apellido 4; Correo: Teléfono: Edad:
```

Por el momento tengo este código el cual me hace una comparación de ambos archivos y me hace un print de los elementos totalmente idénticos:

```
Fichero1 = open('fichero_nombre.txt', 'r')
Fichero2 = open('fichero_prueba.txt', 'r')
 
lista1 = []
lista2 = []
final = []

for line in Fichero2:
    lista1.append(line)
     
for line in Fichero1:
    lista2.append(line)
     
for duplicado in lista1:
    if duplicado in lista2:
        final.append(duplicado)  

    else:
        final.append('No')
 
open("output.txt", "w").write("\n".join(("".join(item)) for item in final))
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que hace que un elemento sea coincidente? ¿Qué es el número después de Nombre y Apellido?

Comment: Hola Jacobo,  el número es para identificar que son personas diferentes, era por no poner nombres y apellidos reales, la idea es que lo que haga coincidentes sean el nombre y apellido y que me busque ese nombre y apellido en el otro archivo para darme los valores que van detrás.

Answer (score 0):

Hay un patrón común para parear archivos, listas, etc. Voy a resolverlo usando dos listas, para facilitar la comprensión; adaptarlo para archivos es trivial.

El principio es que ambos conjuntos de datos están ordenados por la misma llave. Lo que hago es examinar el primer elemento en cada lista:

- Si son iguales, el elemento va a la salida y avanzo ambas listas.
- Si son distintos, avanzo la lista que tenga el menor elemento.

Esto lo ejecuto hasta acabar con una o ambas listas.

```
lista1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
lista2 = [5,8,9,14,15]
resultado = []

i = 0   # Recorre lista1
j = 0   # Recorre lista2

while i < len(lista1) and j < len(lista2):
    if lista1[i] == lista2[j]:
        resultado.append(lista1[i])
        i += 1
        j += 1
    elif lista1[i] < lista2[j]:
        i += 1
    else:
        j += 1

print(resultado)
```

produce:

```
[5, 8, 9]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Hola Candid Moe, lo primero de todo muchas gracias por tu tiempo, en parte si que es lo que busco, ya que me saca los elementos comunes, igual no me he expresado bien,  lo que busco es un código que me compare dos listas una con nombres únicamente y otra con nombres y datos sobre ese nombre como puede ser el correo etc, y que ya sea en otro archivo o printeado en consola se me guarden los nombres con datos de la lista de nombres. es algo lioso por lo que si no lo entiendes te lo trato de explicar de otra forma. Una vez más muchas gracias.

Comment: @InspectorMapache. Entendí bien tu problema; es sólo que me da flojera hacerte el código completo. Con lo que te dí, tienes para resolverlo.

Comment: @InspectorMapache Candid moe te dió los ladrillos. Ahora, toca que construyas la casa. Si la hacen por ti, nunca aprenderas a construir casas.

Answer (score 0):

En situaciones en las que tienes que buscar un elemento que ya existe en una fuente de datos previa, es bueno utilizar una estructura de datos de tipo `hash`. En este caso, un `set` para saber que nombre tenemos en el `archivo1` y cuando leemos el `archivo2` podamos saber de forma inmediata que nombres estaban en el primer archivo.

```
# Usamos un set para saber que personas existen
# en archivo1.txt
personas = set()

file = open("archivo1.txt", "r")
for persona in file:
    personas.add(persona.strip())
file.close()

coincidentes = []
file = open("archivo2.txt", "r")
for datos in file:
    # Los datos están separados del nombre por un
    # punto y coma (;), hagamos split del texto
    # para obtener el nombre
    datos_separados = datos.split(";")
    nombre = datos_separados[0].strip()

    # Si el nombre esta en el set personas, agregamos
    # la línea de texto (o los datos completos)
    # al array de coincidentes
    if nombre in personas:
        coincidentes.append(datos.strip())
file.close()

print(coincidentes)
```

Mi solución se basa en que el formato de los archivos es el que mostraste en tu pregunta.

Hice un [Replit](https://replit.com/join/agrkvhbuzq-jacobotapia) para que puedas correr el código y ver como funciona.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo y por la ayuda, me sirve cuando ambos ficheros tienen los mismos datos escritos en la linea pero si por ejemplo en el archivo 1 tengo escrito "Inspector Mapache correo: hola@gmail.com" y en el otro archivo solo tengo escrito "Inspector Mapache" aunque existan elemenos coincidentes no me hace un print de toda la linea, igual no es posible haceerlo en python y me estoy comiendo la cabeza para nada xD, una vez más muchas gracias :D

Comment: Se puede hacer. El problema es que no clarificaste en tu pregunta los posibles casos que tendrían tus archivos. Tu pregunta indica que un archivo solo tiene nombres y otro nombres + información. Nunca se menciona que los datos en ambos archivos pueden venir con diferentes formatos.

Comment: @InspectorMapache te recomiendo siempre aclarar lo que haga falta para dar una respuesta. Asi evitas que los que responden hayan gastado tiempo y esfuerzo al cohete.